# Anonymous thread class not able to access non static instance variables

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static

I am trying to access instance variable inside a Thread anonymous class . I am getting an error here saying to make it static . The point here is if i can access "this" keyword inside the anonymous class which treats it as its current object holder, then why is it not able to access the instance variables in a non static way .

```
public class AnonymousThreadDemo {
    int num;

    public AnonymousThreadDemo(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Anonymous " + num); // Why cant we access num instance variable
                System.out.println("Anonymous " + this); // This can be accessed in a nonstatic way
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is a `non static` field, it belongs to a specific instance. You can not reference it in `static main` directly, because a `static` method can be called without creating an instance.

`this` is actually referencing `thread`, it is a local variable, when you execute `run`, the `thread` must have been created.

If you try reference `AnonymousThreadDemo.this` in `main`, you will get same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous " + AnonymousThreadDemo.this); // compile error
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

---

This is ok, you can reference a local variable in local class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous " + num);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

---

This is ok, you can reference a non static local class field in its method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        int num = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Anonymous " + num);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

---

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing) for more.

Comment: I was confusing the this keyword with the main class . Kudos to the examples :)

Answer (score 1):

`num` is non static that means it will come after static main in the memory. Hence when main will try to point `num` it won't be available in the memory ie. It still won't be declared yet.